# Cannot access `properties` key/value content when querying ArcGIS Feature Service for GeoJSON

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

Using ArcGIS with a developer account, I created a new layer, uploaded a .geojson file, and happily followed along the ["query a feature layer"](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/query-a-feature-layer/) tutorial on their labs site. I successfully generated an OAuth Token in Postman, but when I changed the "f" (format) value in the x-www-form-urlencoded body to "geojson" it looks similar to the originally GeoJSON file, but the properties are missing/null and the only key info included are the Polygon coordinates. The data remains in the ArcGIS Dashboard but isn't included in the data. Any advice? Is this a bug?

Original File (.geojson):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [50.0115001901903, 50.2259915257836, 0],
          [50.0115418500254, 50.225991583611, 0],
          [50.0115447598285, 50.2242567612666, 0],
          [50.0115031005844, 50.2242567034437, 0],
          [50.0115001901903, 50.2259915257836, 0]
        ]
      ],
      "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "ID": "asdf98d0-fa90-4293-a780-a6988f5486f7",
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "CreationDate": "Wed, 17 June 2020 18:40:41 GMT",
      "Editor": "dkoch"
    }
  }]
}
```

Received file from POST `/0/query` rest endpoint with f: geojson, token: (working token), where: 1=1:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            50.0115001901903,
                            50.2259915257836
                        ],
                        [
                            50.0115418500254,
                            50.225991583611
                        ],
                        [
                            50.0115447598285,
                            50.2242567612666
                        ],
                        [
                            50.0115031005844,
                            50.2242567034437
                        ],
                        [
                            50.0115001901903,
                            50.2259915257836
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the "outFields" parameter.

To return all available fields I believe its "outFields=*"

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. Still new lol

Comment: No problem! we all were new at some point. If it solved it please mark the answer as correct, thanks!